# bcmath sometimes returns float, and sometimes round result

Tags: php, bcmath

I have a variable `$newTime`, which is time in seconds made by `mktime()`, and I want to convert it into number of days.

In this case it is over `86.400` (which is a number of seconds in a day), and I try to divide it by `86.400` to get number of days (rounded).

But sometimes I get:

```
Case 1: 87951 / 86400 = 1.0179513888 (1 day ago)
Case 2: 156257 / 86400 = 1.8085300925 (2 days ago)
```

and sometimes:

```
Case 1: 87986 / 86400 = 1 (Should be 1 day ago)
Case 2: 156292 / 86400 = 1 (Should be 2 days ago)
```

This is the code:

```
$newTime = round(bcdiv($newTime, bcmul("24", bcmul("60", "60"))),0);
```

When I don't use bcmath, just the regular math (`$newTime / (60*60*24)`), I get floating results every time.

Comment: So... why do you need to use bcmath, if it's working well without it?

Comment: Well, yeah, but it is bugging me now that it doesn't work with bcmath...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set the scale using `bcscale`? If it is set to `0`, it could explain the behaviour. Please, try to call `bcscale(100)` before your computation;

Comment: You could also check/change the default scale with the `bcmath.scale` INI option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
$newTime = round( $newTime / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

With no bcmath at all please.

Examples:

```
$newTime = 156292;
$newTime = round( $newTime / (60 * 60 * 24));
echo $newTime; //2 Always

$newTime = 87986;
$newTime = round( $newTime / (60 * 60 * 24));
echo $newTime; //1 Always
```

Comment: I already said that I tried with regulart math, and it is ok, but I am still interested in the bcmath solution :)

Comment: You would need to convert the string result from `bcmath` to a normal number anyway, to use `round`. So it doesn't make any sense to use it

Comment: When using round(bcdiv($newTime, bcmul("24", bcmul("60", "60")))), there is no need for any other conversion

Comment: round converts the argument to a number